# How to find if Mongodb is running in auth mode in shell script?

Tags: mongodb, shell, unix, mongodb-shell

I am having a mongodb instance running which is running  auth mode in my server machine. Currently I am using a shell scipt to get whether there is a mongodb instance running or not. How Can I check whether if the mongodb is running in a auth mode or non auth mode .

Comment: I think you should check with mongostat utility http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just want to test whether you can connect to a MongoDB server without authentication via `bash`, you can use a script similar to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Connect to MongoDB address (host:port/dbname) specified as first parameter
# If no address specified, `mongo` default will be localhost:27017/test
isAuth=`mongo --eval "db.getUsers()" $1 | grep "not auth"`

if [ -z "$isAuth" ] ;
then
   echo "mongod auth is NOT enabled"
   exit 1
else
   echo "mongod auth is ENABLED"
   exit 0
fi
```

Example output:

```
$ ./isAuthEnabled.sh localhost:27017
mongod auth is ENABLED

$ ./isAuthEnabled.sh localhost:27777
mongod auth is NOT enabled
```

The only parameter for this script is an an optional MongoDB address to connect to (host:port/dbname); the `mongo` shell defaults to using `localhost:27017/test`.

The script does a simple check on whether users can be listed without permission.

If auth is properly enabled, the `db.getUsers()` command should return an error like:

```
  "Error: not authorized on test to execute command { usersInfo: 1.0 }"
```

##### Newer versions

Note that the error message has changed in the newer version of MongoDB, so you may need to `grep "requires authentication"` instead of `not auth`

#### Note: Localhost Exception

By default (as at MongoDB 3.0) there is a [`localhost exception`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#localhost-exception) that allows you to create a first [user administrator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/) for a deployment by connecting via `localhost`. Once at least one user has been added, the localhost exception is automatically disabled.

If you want to check the full security of your deployment, it's definitely worth reviewing the [MongoDB Security checklist](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-checklist/).