# MongoDB Authentication not enabled on Linux Server

Tags: linux, mongodb, authentication

I have installed `mongodb` on Linux Server - Ubuntu 16.04. It is up and running, as I have tested it through `putty`. So, next thing I wanted to do was setup authentication on `mongodb`.

I have created users with roles following this [blog](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-secure-mongodb-nosql-production-database/).

This is my `etc/mongodb.conf`

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

I have setup user in `db` in `system.users` collection for two `dbs` with roles and restarted `mongod` on server.

Here, is the script test.sh to test the authentication status of mongodb. Ref was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949586/how-to-find-if-mongodb-is-running-in-auth-mode-in-shell-script).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Connect to MongoDB address (host:port/dbname) specified as first parameter
# If no address specified, `mongo` default will be localhost:27017/test
isAuth=`mongo --eval "db.getUsers()" $1 | grep "not auth"`

if [ -z "$isAuth" ] ;
then
   echo "mongod auth is NOT enabled"
   exit 1
else
   echo "mongod auth is ENABLED"
   exit 0
fi
```

When I run the script I got `mongod auth is NOT enabled`. Moreover, I am also not having problem inserting or viewing database form shell.

So, my questions in summary are:

1. Is what I have done for authentication on `/etc/mongodb.conf` correct? If not what might be the right way?
2. How can I test if authentication is enabled on MongoDb?

*P.S: I created Linux Server from Azure if that helps.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say but it was a typo I was doing `systemctl start mongodb`, it was actually `mongod`.

```
systemctl start mongod
```

made it up and running. I hope the resources I used for enabling `authorization` on Mongodb and Bash Script to check if authorization is working, will be a good resources for developers starting to develop using MongoDB.

Comment: same here! I had done the exact same miss-type! You have saved me long hours of slog that would have gone nowhere! One beer to you!